# Background Image for Title Slide in Rmarkdown (xaringan) not working

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I have added a background image to the title slide in my xaringan presentation based on this post: [How can I add an image to the title slide in Rmarkdown (xaringan)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74540254/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-the-title-slide-in-rmarkdown-xaringan). The image shows up perfectly when I compile to html. The issue is when I try to share the html file outputted, the image does not show up in the background.

I have included "self-contained: true" in the yaml. All other pictures in the presentation are displayed correctly. It is only the title slide picture that is not being displayed when I try to share the html file. Is there a way to include the picture without having to share any other files? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.